# How to Animate Color of Header Back Button in React Native React Navigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to animate the color of header back button from color grey background with white arrow icon to color white background with black arrow icon in react native react navigation 5.

[image]

[image]

I tried to do the following, but it is throwing `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

```
const yOffset = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

const backButtonBackgroundColorAnimation = yOffset.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 130],
        outputRange: ['rgba(0,0,0,0.4)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'], // gray transparent to transparent
        extrapolate: "clamp"
      });

      const backArrowColorAnimation = yOffset.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 130],
        outputRange: ['rgb(255,255,255)', 'rgb(0,0,0)'], // white to black
        extrapolate: "clamp"
    });
```

```
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';

headerLeft: (props) => (                          
              <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor: backButtonOpacity}} >                           
                  <Icon                       
                    name='arrowleft'
                    type='antdesign'
                    color='white'
                    size={24}                            
                    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor:backButtonBackgroundColorAnimation, color:backArrowColorAnimation, borderRadius:500, padding: 5, marginLeft:10}}
                    {...props}
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }}
                    />
              </Animated.View>                                                       
          )
```

```
<Animated.ScrollView        
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: {
                    y: yOffset,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: false }
          )}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
```

Comment: Where does the Icon component come from?

Comment: You are setting background color to backButtonOpacity, this seems wrong since opacity and color are not the same.

Comment: also when you set color in style color:backArrowColorAnimation this seems wrong, you should set the color on <Icon color={backArrowColorAnimation}> instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the react-native-elements icon is not an animated component. You can make it animated by using

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';
const AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Icon);
```

Also adjust it so that you use style instead of container style.

```
headerLeft: (props) => (
    <Animated.View style={{ opacity: headerOpacity }}>
      <AnimatedIcon
        name="arrowleft"
        type="antdesign"
        color={backArrowColorAnimation}
        size={24}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: backButtonBackgroundColorAnimation,
          borderRadius: 500,
          padding: 5,
          marginLeft: 10,
        }}
        {...props}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
    </Animated.View>
  ),
```

For a full code example see the code on this snack https://snack.expo.io/@dannyhw/react-navigation-animated-header2

Answer (score 1):

I guess using `useNativeDriver: true` to the interpolation will solve the problem.

But I did not tried it. [Please check the header animated view example here.](https://medium.com/hackernoon/react-native-animated-header-using-animated-and-scrollview-9749255c149a)
If it's not help you please share your Icon component too.

Comment: Hi, i tried setting` useNativeDriver` to `true`, unfortunately it does not solve the issue. The Icon is `import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';`

Comment: this wont work because color cannot be animated using the native driver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the background color and arrow icon color, then why do you need Animated.View?

You can simply use the navigation.setParams() to change the color of the header left and arror icon.

setParams will works like setState for update the route params.

Comment: He is using animated.view because he wants to animate the color change. Using set params would just change it instantly.